# How to enable experimental features of nodejs in serverless framework or AWS lamda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I am using [Serverless-Framework](https://www.serverless.com/) for my nodejs application, but application requires the experimental features of nodejs to be enabled, how can I do this in serverless using `sls deploy` cmd. or direct on AWS lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the feature is behind a flag, you can set the  [`NODE_OPTIONS`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#node_optionsoptions) env var, which [lambda supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-modify.html).

If the feature is not on the [AWS-provided node runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) (as of late 2021 v14.x is the highest version), you can deploy a [custom runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html#runtimes-custom-build) or a [Docker container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-images.html).